# Types to check if the VALUE exists

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion, typescript-generics

I have such object ( which maybe converted to anything, it is just for checking types, so feel free to edit it as you like for your advices )
it has more than 500 entries so the following is just an example part of it.

```
export const binanceCoins = {
AGLD: 'ETH',
STPT: 'ETH',
MXN: 'FIAT_MONEY',
UGX: 'FIAT_MONEY',
GLM: 'ETH',
RAY: 'SOL',
NEAR: 'BSC' || 'NEAR' || 'BNB',
AUDIO: 'ETH',
ADADOWN: 'ETF',
FARM: 'BSC' || 'ETH',
SDG: 'FIAT_MONEY',
XNO: 'NANO',
DGB: 'DGB',}
```

and I have such function

```
const topUpFromBinance = async (chainName: string, tokenName: keyof typeof binanceCoins) => {}
```

So I need typescript to check the args from the **binanceCoins** object, and as you can see I did it for the tokenName arg, and it's working now I can enter only the tokenNames that are keys of the binanceCoins object
[image]

And now I need to check the first arg - **chainName** to be correct only if the respective key has such value!
For example if you look at the screenshot above the key is AGLD and it has only the 'ETH' value in the binanceCoins object, so anything other than that should be concidered as error by the typescript.
Another eexample: if the tokenName is 'NEAR' the chainName arg can be 'BSC' | 'NEAR' | 'BNB'.
Another example: if the tokenname is 'SDG' the chainName can be only 'FIAT_MONEY'.
I hope the idea is clear.

But how to do it? is it even possible for typescript?
please remember that this object has over 500 entries so I cannot do interface for every entry of it...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The property value of `NEAR` does not make sense as it will always be `"BSC"`

Comment: Did you mean `NEAR: 'BSC' as 'BSC' | 'NEAR' | 'BNB',`?

Comment: well I just meant that it can be any of the values... BSC or NEAR or BNB

Comment: Then try the string literal union type in the above comment `'a' | 'b'` as that's what I figured you meant but I wasn't sure

Comment: if throws an error 'The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2363)' this way

Comment: Try https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wEYEtkENkLADCEOqcAvHAN4BQccAggOIAyAIgFxwBEAogBUAEjwA09OAGUBABQHd+wsRICyADQByCgGIBJRgID6KgPIa+ATWUMAqszU79R0+aviGbFQsEj3cAEqMFgqSJqzWcOaM-goAQpJEPHC45DzxiXAAPrxR-knZaRqxEYw27Lom3kp+jOy1JgDqWryC2hHa0V686Ukp3Qn5LdUSkuzMjgbGZpYRmpU5jBomEWOxCqvKAL7J5EhoMADctLQwAJ5gwHAkZJRwZxcQAGZw2HgExKRoR7R76HcQYBsYG0UAgAFtYjh8IRbilTgQ4AAeADScFAMGAyAAJuQANbAU5PK6fVAAPgAFBIEAALXA4DS4MHAbjXNAAbWRAF00SAMdjyFBgLgsSgADanODoKA4ADmbO5AH5iWQOZy2cgAK5gjDAKDclkk1V+GAQfHIBlM7jI2gASkopJocE23xOAKBIPBkLehHJhWKohyfGiPBtRxNgOBoIhUPevp8YkDwdDcAA9Cm0VBQVBaEA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need to [const assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) the `binanceCoins` for it to have exact types for the values instead of widening `string` type.

```
const binanceCoins = {
  AGLD: "ETH",
  STPT: "ETH",
  MXN: "FIAT_MONEY",
  UGX: "FIAT_MONEY",
  GLM: "ETH",
  RAY: "SOL",
  NEAR: "BSC" || "NEAR" || "BNB",
  AUDIO: "ETH",
  ADADOWN: "ETF",
  FARM: "BSC" || "ETH",
  SDG: "FIAT_MONEY",
  XNO: "NANO",
  DGB: "DGB",
} as const;
```

You should use a generic parameter for the `keyof typeof binanceCoins` and get the value of that specific property.

```
type Coins = typeof binanceCoins;

const topUpFromBinance = async <K extends keyof Coins>(
  chainName: Coins[K],
  tokenName: K
) => {};
```

Usage:

```
topUpFromBinance('ETF', 'ADADOWN')
topUpFromBinance('RANDOM', 'ADADOWN') // invalid
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253790/discussion-on-answer-by-wonderflame-types-to-check-if-the-value-exists); please do not continue the discussion here.** Please ensure that the answer has been updated to reflect the outcome of discussion/debugging.